# Insert data on active worksheet

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm trying to insert the data in active sheet of excel

```
    Sub click()
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object

    'Start a new workbook in Excel
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add


    'Add data to cells of the first worksheet in the new workbook
    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Last Name"
    oSheet.Range("B1").Value = "First Name"
    oSheet.Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
    oSheet.Range("A2").Value = "Doe"
    oSheet.Range("B2").Value = "John"

    'Save the Workbook and Quit Excel
    oBook.SaveAs("c:\abc.xlsx")
    oExcel.Quit
End Sub
```

What this code does is on click of the button (the button appears in ribbon of excel),the above function gets called.new sheet gets created and data gets entered into it.
Actually what I want is to insert data into current sheet without creating a file.

Please anyone who can helpout

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the code within Excel? The current code looks like it's within another app that supports VBA.

Comment: yes i'm coding it in visual studio

Comment: Not sure about VS - I've added my answer and it _may_ work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was pretty simple...this is how we can get the access to current sheet of workbook..without creating or saving a file

```
 Dim activeWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)
    With activeWorksheet
        .Range("A1").Value = "Last Name"
        .Range("B1").Value = "First Name"
        .Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
        .Range("A2").Value = "Doe"
        .Range("B2").Value = "John"
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code is within Excel then this will work:

```
Sub click()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("A1").Value = "Last Name"
        .Range("B1").Value = "First Name"
        .Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
        .Range("A2").Value = "Doe"
        .Range("B2").Value = "John"
    End With
End Sub
```

From another application such as Access this will work:

```
Sub click1()
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Object

    'Start a new workbook in Excel
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("c:\def.xlsx")

    'Add data to cells of the first worksheet in the opened workbook
    Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    With oSheet
        .Range("A1").Value = "Last Name"
        .Range("B1").Value = "First Name"
        .Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
        .Range("A2").Value = "Doe"
        .Range("B2").Value = "John"
    End With

    'Save the Workbook and Quit Excel
    oBook.SaveAs ("c:\abc.xlsx")
    oExcel.Quit
End Sub
```

Note:  If you want to save it under the same name just use `oBook.Save`
       If you want Excel to be visible use `oExcel.Visible = True` after you've created it.

Comment: No .its outside excel..Anyways Thanks

Comment: The second example should work then - not sure about VS, but worked from Access.